# Extract one element per batch from Tensorflow 2.1 tensor

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

Lets assume I have a batch consisting of two tensor, and the tensors in the patch are of size 3.

```
data = [[0.3, 0.5, 0.7], [-0.3, -0.5, -0.7]]
```

Now I want to extract from each tensor in the patch a single element base on an index:

```
index = [0, 2]
```

**The output should therefore be**

```
out = [0.3, -0.7] # Get index 0 from the first tensor in the batch and index 2 from the second tensor in the batch.
```

Of course this should be extendable to large batch sizes. The dimension of `index` is equal to the batch size.

I tried to apply `tf.gather` and `tf.gather_nd` but I did not get the results I wanted.

For example the code below print `0.7` and **not** the desired result specified above:

```
data = [[0.3, 0.5, 0.7], [-0.3, -0.5, 0.7]]

index = [0, 2]
out = tf.gather_nd(data, index)

print(out.numpy())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the batch size you can do the following,

```
import tensorflow as tf
data = tf.constant([[0.3, 0.5, 0.7], [-0.3, -0.5, 0.7]])

index = [0,2]
gather_inds = np.stack([np.arange(len(index)), index], axis=1)
out = tf.gather_nd(data, gather_inds)
```

Why your gather didn't work is because you are gathering from the inner most dimension. Therefore, your indices need to be as same as the rank of your `data` tensor. In other words, your indices should be,

```
[0,0] and [1,2]
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!